# Undefined symbols _RCTRegisterModule on latest version of xCode and macOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

When attempting to build my react-native app, I get Undefined symbols _RCTRegisterModule on numerous packages and error: linker command failed with exit code 1

When right clicking on this to see in logs it doesnt show anything either.

Building React-native application
did npm install
did pod install and update
reinstalled the node modules folder
cleaned build
latest version of xCode and macOS

no matter what I do -- such as changing thee s.dependency to react-core from 'react' or whatever the other posts have recommended I still get the error Undefined symbols _RCTRegisterModule on numerous packages.

Have updated packages, downgraded packages, reinstalled packages, manually linked in the build phase, pod deintegrate and install and update and the likes and I still get this issue preventing me from building anymore.

This only happened after getting a new mac, was never an issue on the old mac which was a 2019 macbook pro intel i5. I have mirrored the settings and directly copied the folders to a T and I still get this issue. I am unsure what else to do.

System:
Macbook pro M2 Ultra 16GB 14"